# How to change the whole URL in address bar without refreshing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I would like to replace an url without page refresh.

I need to change:

https://example.com

to

https://banana.com

I tried `window.history.pushState({page: "another"}, "another page", "banana.com");`

But it only attached `banana.com` to the `example.com`

Comment: I highly doubt that this is even possible. This would probably confuse users and likely be used for evil; what is your reason for wanting to do this? Also, how is this related to jQuery?

Comment: Most likly he wants to harm users due the fact that there is currently a race-condition exploit which fits this matter: https://thehackernews.com/2018/09/browser-address-spoofing-vulnerability.html

Answer (score 1):

Barring a (quick-to-be patched) bug or exploit, this - showing a totally different domain name than the one you're actually on - isn't possible. It'd be used maliciously, for things like phishing - if you could make `https://www.paypal.com/` show up as the URL, you'd be able to easily steal credentials.

The History API can be used to change the current path seamlessly, but **not** the hostname.